# Как отфильтровать метки на Яндекс карте?

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api, карты

На карте 3000 объектов, выгружаются из JSON. Весь функционал построен с помощью ObjectManager. Несколько кастомных кнопок с чекбоксами и фильтрацией по виду объекта с помощью setFilter().

```
function mapFilter () {
var item = $( "input[type="checkbox"]" );
obj = {};
item.each(function( index ) {
    obj[$( this ).val()] = $( this ).prop('checked');
});
    objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(obj));
};

function getFilterFunction(categories){
    return function(obj){
      var content = obj.properties.typeObgect;
      return categories[content];
    }
};
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(mapFilter);
```

Необходимо добавить фильтрацию по цене "от до" (значения берутся из инпутов), с сохранением результата предыдущего фильтра.
Конструкция типа:

```
objectManager.setFilter('properties.cost >= "10000" && properties.cost <= "20000"');
```

работает, а как объединить результаты двух фильтров не знаю.
Подскажите куда копать.
Фрагмент JSON:

```
"properties": {
            "code": "160058",
            "cost": "8500",
            "typeObgect": "home",
            "balloonContentBody": ""
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое решение:

```
function mapFilter () {
  var item = $( "input[type="checkbox"]" );
  obj = {};
  item.each(function( index ) {
    obj[$( this ).val()] = $( this ).prop('checked');
  });
objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(obj));
};
function getFilterFunction(categories){
var costMin = $("#input_cost_min").val(),
    costMax = $("#input_cost_max").val();
  return function(obj){
    if (obj.properties.cost >= costMin && obj.properties.cost <= costMax) {
        var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
        return categories[content];
    };
  };
};


$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(mapFilter);
$('input[type="button"]').click(mapFilter);
```